# Why "where" of mongodb is not working in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a complete beginner in `node.js` and `mongodb` so please do excuse me if my question seem to be foolish.Basically I'm trying to perform the following operation by using `where` and `or` operator to get some refined result from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27833585/8027365) but it's showing error.

Code:

```
//here "data" is the emitted socket object from client side
var string = data.search.replace(/[\/\\#@+()$~%'":*?<>{}]/g, '')
        var regex = new RegExp(["^", string].join(""), "i");
        db.collection("user_information").find()
        .where('_id').ne(data.userId)
        .or([
           {email: regex}, 
           {fullname:regex}
         ])
        .select('fullname email')
        .exec(function(err, res){
         console.log(res)
        })
```

Error:

```
TypeError: db.collection(...).find(...).where is not a function
at C:\chat\mongo.js:1898:14
at connectCallback (C:\Users\Srinu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:515:5)
at C:\Users\Srinu\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:430:11
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you linked to regards the use of the [Mongoose ORM library](http://mongoosejs.com/), not the standard MongoDB driver for Node. The former is built on top of the latter, and exposes a higher-level API. If you want to use the code from the other question, you'll need to install and import Mongoose.

Alternatively, if you want to continue to use the Node driver on its own, you can perform queries by passing a [query object](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) as the first parameter of `find` - for example, your first 'where' would look something like this:

```
db.collection("user_information").find({
    _id: { $ne: data.userId }
})
```

I would recommend reading the docs for both [MongoDB itself](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-documents/) and the [Node driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) for more info.